# Server receives no data from NSURLSessionUploadTask

Tags: ios, django, afnetworking, multipartform-data, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I'm trying to upload a file via a multipart request using NSURLSessionUploadTask via AFNetworking. The request executes and receives a response from the server, but the server is not receiving the data in the form.

iOS code

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSURL URLWithString:URLString relativeToURL:self.baseURL] absoluteString];
NSError *error = nil;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:urlString parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    //
   [formData appendPartWithFileData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]
                               name:@"video"
                           fileName:[path lastPathComponent]
                           mimeType:@"video/mp4"];
} error:&error];

if ([account isAuthenticated]) {;
    NSString *authHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", account.accessToken];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:@{@"Authorization": authHeader}];
}

NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [self uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * __unused response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {

    } else {

    }
}];
[task resume];
```

Here is the header info for the request from AFNetworkingActivityLogger:

```
POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/': {
"Accept-Language" = "en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5";
Authorization = "Bearer 270f985de7ebf0aa49b7ff1cad8377e007141f94";
"Content-Length" = 225974;
"Content-Type" = "multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+4597B504492E1006";
"User-Agent" = "Test/1.0 (iPad Simulator; iOS 7.1; Scale/1.00)";
} (null)
```

I'm using Django on the server side. Here's the test view:

```
class UploadView(View):

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    logger.debug("FILES: {0} | DATA: {1}".format(request.FILES, request.POST))
    return HttpResponse(content=json.dumps({"test": "2"}), content_type='application/json')
```

But both the FILES and POST objects are empty:

```
FILES: <MultiValueDict: {}> | DATA: <QueryDict: {}>
```

This works without the multipart request- just sending a POST request without a file upload the QueryDict is populated. One thing I'm unsure about is the fact that the body of the request is "(null)" according to the AFNetworkingActivityLogger output.

Any help is appreciated! I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for -[NSURLSession uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:] (looks like that is what you are using):

> ... The body stream and body data in this request object
>   are ignored, and NSURLSession calls its delegate’s
>   URLSession:task:needNewBodyStream: method to provide the body data.

Have you implemented that delegate method?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013435-CH1-SW28

Comment: Ack- RTFM fail on my part- that was indeed the problem. It turned out that I needed to support iOS6 anyway, so I wasn't able to use NSURLSession ultimately, but this is what would have solved my problem. Thanks for pointing this out!